# How SAS computes Ridge values in PROC PHREG

Tags: sas, survival-analysis

The `itprint` option in the `class` statement of SAS `proc phreg` causes the display of the iteration history. This includes a Ridge value, along with the beta values and log likelihoods for each iteration. Ridge is usually zero but is non-zero whenever a log likelihood would otherwise be more negative than the log likelihood for the previous iteration. I need to know how SAS computes that ridge value and I can find nothing in the Details section for that procedure, or anywhere else.

It appears that, by default, that Ridge value is always `0.0001 * 2^n`, and that SAS starts with `n=0` and increments `n` until log likelihood is less negative than in the previous iteration. But I have tested at least one example where SAS used `Ridge=0.4096` when `Ridge=0.2048` would suffice.

Update: I now think that SAS is iterating `4^n`, rather than `2^n`. That explains skipping `2048` and is consistent with my testing so far.

So I think I have answered my own question and would now like academic support for this method. I'll likely seek that at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) as [Robert Penridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214994/robert-penridge) and [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1623007/joe) suggest.

Comment: If you don't have any success here, you should consider flagging the question to have it migrated over to Cross Validated (http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't think this would be an appropriate CV question; this is asking how a particular software performs a computation, not how generally one does so.  Certainly don't cross-post it, you should flag for migration if you're looking for more generic statistical advice.

Comment: That said, if you were to post this somewhere else I'd suggest the [SAS Community forums](http://communities.sas.com).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Joe. I am ultimately after an academic paper or text supporting whatever method SAS uses. I thought comparing SAS's displayed values with the calculations in my own VB routine would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Joe, I think at this point I have figured out how SAS computes and uses Ridge, using the ITHIST output and some documentation at support.sas.com. I'd like to see some academic support for this method, which is why I considered CV. But maybe that's not appropriate for CV.  I hadn't heard of CV before today. Thanks again.

Comment: Academic support for that method would be fine for CV, I think.  The initial question (How does SAS...) wouldn't be, but once you're in the realm of something that no longer really depends on a particular software to answer you're fine.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please post an answer and accept it so that others may benefit from your findings as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PHREG fails to converge, that is, when a log likelihood value is more negative than in the previous iteration, the procedure computes a ridge value. This value is `RIDGEINIT * 2^n`, with `n` incremented until either the log likelihood value becomes less negative, or the ridge value reaches `RIDGEMAX`.

The default `RIDGEINIT` is `1e-4`.

The default `RIDGEMAX` is `MAX(1, RIDGEINIT) * 2000`.